# how do you execute an http post in Java?

Tags: java, http, post

Here is the code I am using.  Instead of posting data to the page, it is downloading it like a regular text file.  So, I am actually getting the html code returned and the form is not being submitted.

I know the html form works.  If I open it in a browser, I can post to it and my data appears in my database.  I'm guessing I'm missing a parameter or something.

```
public void testComm ()
{
try
    {
    URL         url;
    URLConnection   urlConn;
    DataOutputStream    printout;
    DataInputStream input;

    url = new URL ("http://mysite.com/myform.html");

    // URL connection channel.
    urlConn = url.openConnection();

    // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
    urlConn.setDoInput (true);

    // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
    urlConn.setDoOutput (true);

    // No caching, we want the real thing.
    urlConn.setUseCaches (false);

    // Specify the content type.
    urlConn.setRequestProperty
    ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Send POST output.
    printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ());

    String content =
    "txtLevelName=" + URLEncoder.encode ("level1") +
    "&txtLevelData=" + URLEncoder.encode ("abcd");

    printout.writeBytes (content);
    printout.flush ();
    printout.close ();

    // Get response data.
    input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ());

    String str;
    while (null != ((str = input.readLine())))
    {
    System.out.println (str);
    }

    input.close ();

    }
catch (MalformedURLException me)
    {
    System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + me);
    }
catch (IOException ioe)
    {
    System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're avoiding something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and letting it do most of the work for you? And I'm not sure what you mean by getting HTML back; are you saying you don't get HTML back when you post the form from the browser?

Comment: Are you posting it to the form or the action??? please print your html and the action script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're already sending a POST request. It's the `urlConn.setDoOutput(true)` which sets the request method to POST. Apparently you're sending the request to the wrong URL. Open the HTML page in your browser. Rightclick and *View Source*. Locate the HTML `<form>` element in the HTML source. It should look something like:

```html
<form action="http://mysite.com/somescript" method="post">
```

Check its `action` attribute. That's exactly the URL which you have to POST to.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are not doing it right. Looks like you are posting it to the form instead of the action.

Answer (score 2):

what I'm doing (I know there are frameworks for this, but i wanted it light-weight):

```
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if(!postString.isEmpty()) {
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postString.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            final OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(postString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        }
```

postString is the same as your content string

// edit: oh and as sid mentioned above: your url is a html page???

Answer (score 2):

you can try **jsoup**: http://jsoup.org/

it's VERY easy to use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com")
  .data("query", "Java")
  .post();
```

Load a Document from a URL:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url